# Can I use the userId intead of the jwt token?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authorization

What if I hash the userId and store it in the local storage. And then on every route, I send a request to the server and the server finds the user by that id ( unhashed ) which will be in the authorization header.
Will it be considered good practice and will it be safe ?

Comment: What if I hash some random number and put it in my local storage…?!

Comment: Also, "unhashing" isn't a thing.

Comment: It's never a good practice to store your user information / tokens in the localStorage. You should look more into access tokens and refresh tokens that can be stored in cookies.

Comment: but where should I store my jwt token

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are several points to consider here:

1. Storing sensitive data (passwords, tokens etc.) is generally a bad idea, because it can be a security risk (XSS) and is also difficult to handle, because people clear their caches and you sort of give up control of the data you put in there. Another way would be to use cookies, but those can also lead to security vulnerabilities (CSRF/XSRF exploits)
2. JWT is a very secure and commonly used strategy (if you use it right). It's important to store the secret safely. It enables you to authenticate users without the need to store a session in a database, because it has an expiration date. You should read more about JWT online to see how it works in detail.
3. Hashing something doesn't mean it's secure. Sure, you can't just "unhash" it, hashing is usually a one way operation (there's a huge discussion about the possibilities of unhashing, but I'm not going to add my opinion to this, just consider it to be impossible at this point). Either way, hashing itself isn't enough to secure information. It matters where you place the hashed information (best to safely store it in a database, isolated from the user and other people).
4. You CAN implement your own authorization strategy, but there are a lot of existing, safe authorization methods. OAuth, API Keys, bearer tokens, they all usually get sent through the authorization header. But you probably wouldn't want to store those keys in your browser.

Hope I could help a bit, if something's unclear, let me know :)

Comment: That's the neat part, you don't :D at least not if you're talking about backend side.
If you're talking about the frontend, then you can either
1. Store the JWT in your localStorage or a cookie, but then you MUST apply best security practices for XSS escaping and such, which is tough
2. or store the token in your application memory and also use a refresh token which you could save in a HttpOnly cookie